# Google analytics site search in localhost

Tags: google-analytics

My google analytics site search is not working.How to set it up locally so that it can reflect in google analytics demo account.

```
  <script>

(function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
            i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
            i[r] = i[r] || function() {
                (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
            }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
            a = s.createElement(o),
                m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
            a.async = 1;
            a.src = g;
            m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
        })(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];


ga('create', 'UA-169....', 'auto');// add your tracking ID here.
ga('send', 'pageview');
  </script>
```

I have added only these few lines and whenever i visit my webiste: "http://localhost:4200/?gsearch=jkn%20drkjebfrjmf" it shows 1 view in google analytics demo account.But not working for site search.Is it because i don't have domain name?

My project is on angular9